# How to use translation with component to make it useful for unit testing

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Most of the components looks like as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { withTranslation } from "react-i18next";

class XYZ extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };
  }

  .....
  .....


  render() {
    const { t } = this.props;

    return (

        ..... 
    );
  }
}

export default withTranslation()(XYZ);
```

or, like below, in case of function components:

```
export const XYZ = withTranslation()(({ t, ...props }) => {
  ....
  return (
    .....
  );
});
```

I wanted to use enzyme shallow as it would only unit test the XYZ component than its child components but with it I face a problem as the first level of component is translation and it doesn't go to Child components inside XYZ. So, I am thinking I may not be writing the components properly. What do you suggest is the right way to write this class and function component so that testing would be easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the container pattern to be rather useful for unit testing. Export the raw component **and** default export the decorated component.

```
export const MyComponent = props => (...);

export default componentDecorator(MyComponent);
```

The default export is for normal app consumption while the regular export is for testing. This allows you to mock all the props you need, or provide test wrappers to inject props normally accessed via context providers.

```
import { MyComponent } from '.'
...
shallow(<MyComponent {...mockTranslationProps} {...otherProps) />)
```

In projects I'm a part of we use react-intl for our translations, which as an `injectItnl` HOC that provides a `intl.formatMessage` function, for the tests I just create a mock intl object where the translation function simply passes it's argument through.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But, if I do that, I get error in unit testing as it is not able to resolve any t("someString") now as the translation t is missing. How do I take care of that?

Comment: You need to provide it. It looks like a function, so something like `t={arg => arg}` so you can pass it a string and it'll simply return the string. Or define a mock ahead of time `tMock = jest.fn(t => t);` and then pass as prop `t={tMock}`.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I have one more question though. Why doesn't the default export works with unit testing? I am getting following error as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59773467/how-to-unit-test-the-component-with-translation. Is there any way I can use the default export only?

Comment: Perhaps this [Difference between Shallow, Mount and render of Enzyme - gist](https://gist.github.com/fokusferit/e4558d384e4e9cab95d04e5f35d4f913) can help explain.